# Send var-value using jquery post, mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use ajax/json to fetch a random row from a mysql-server using a php. The different data from the random row I get is then stored in vars.

```
          $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'api.php',                  
          data: "",                 
          dataType: 'json',         
          success: function(data)         
          {
          var id = data[0];
        .....
```

I then want to use the field ID as an identifyer to update a field in that specific row in the mysql-database using a update.php.

```
     $sql = "UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 +1 WHERE id = '???'";
```

Now, I'm new to using jquery-post, so can somebody help me to pass on the data (the ID-number) AND use it correctly in the update.php?

```
  <script>
  $(document).jkey('a',function() {
         $.post("update.php");
        $('.id').html(data);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );

as you can see in the examples

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: So to pass on the content in the var "id", I would go:

`$.post("update.php", { id: "id"} );` ?

Or should I echo it using PHP? And most importantly, how should things look on the recieving end, the PHP sql-query?

Comment: you will get the variable by the  method used to pass the variable from ajax if method is post than use **$_POST['id']** at the receiving end.

Comment: @punit ; That would leave me with this, is that correct?

    `<script> $(document).jkey('a',function() {$.POST("update.php", id );    }); </script>` 

and at update.php:

    `<?php $id = $_POST['id'];?> <?php $sql = "UPDATE table SET field1 = field1 +1 WHERE id = 'id'";` ? 

Not working, unfortunately.

Comment: i think it's typo but did you put the variable as **WHERE id = '$id'**

Comment: Still not working ;/ Can it be that the original post can't send the variable correctly?

Comment: **$.post("update.php", { id: "id"} )** is correct syntex, i think it's typo but did you put the variable as **WHERE id = '$id'** and also check value of variable are you getting the value?.

Comment: Yes, I checked both and fixed the typo. What's the easiest way to check if the value of the variable is correct? Echo it somehow? 

Edit: I forgot to move the ` $id = $_POST['id'];` inside the right PHP. It now works, but it writes to EVERY row in the mysql-field, so something is clearly wrong.

Comment: well, then your php script is wrong, not jquery... you should check your post variable for valid content.. not just put it into the query...